# Nothing comes up when I try to change the SSH port

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to change the port number, and I've found a few answers on here from the past, most saying that you should use the following code.

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

or

```
modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The modify one (for me) comes back with a "Does not exist"/"Nothing found", and nano brings me back a blank page when people are saying it should have port numbers. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you don't have that file, did you already install openssh-server, so there is something to actually configure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file comes up as blank when trying to edit using `nano` then the file is being created, as it doesn't already exist. This can also happen if you mis-type the filename.

To check whether the file is there:

```
cd /etc/ssh
```

Followed by:

```
ls -lh
```

This will output a list of files in the `/etc/ssh` directory.
If the file doesn't exist, then you may need to reinstall, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you set up ssh.

You already have a ssh client with which you can connect to other machines. But if you want other systems to connect to you, you must install a ssh server like this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Once you did that, edit your ssh congiuration file to change the port:

```
sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Here nano is a command line based text editor. You should change `Port 22` to the port which you want. To exit the editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Finally you need to restart the ssh daemon for the changes to reflect, so on 14.10 or older:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Or if you're running Ubuntu 15.04 or later,

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

That's it!

Comment: Ooh, even stevens on rep points! I've got to +1 for such a complete answer though!

Comment: @Arronical Your answer is to the point. But the OP seems a little inexperienced. So I thought of writing one like this.

Comment: `service` isn't going to cut it if OP is using systemd (15.04 onwards)

Comment: @MrBones I don't have experience with systemd. Would you edit the answer or tell me the command and i will update it myself?

Comment: @daltonfury42 I didn't know off the top of my head either, or I'd have filled it in ^^

Comment: Use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo nano`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, thanks, but just wondering what difference it makes.

Comment: @daltonfury42: `sudoedit` is `sudo -e`. It does more than simply calling $EDITOR with the file; see `man sudoedit`.

Comment: Arronical, @daltonfury42 thanks both of you, I fixed it. And yes, daltonfury42 I am extremely inexperienced. My boss gave me a bunch of tasks to do with setting up ubuntu, writing codes in nano and bash when I had never even heard of these things before. Thank you guys so much. I couldn't decide who to put as the "Answer" because you both helped.